# I want to get specific imageview id?

Tags: android, animation, imageview

[image]

I have 4 imageview when specific imageview is clicked at that time animation load and move to next activity.

Here is my code.

```
        animation1 = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.to_middle);
        animation1.setAnimationListener(this);
        animation2 = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.from_middle);
        animation2.setAnimationListener(this);


    saveContact=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imgSaveContact);
    sendMessage=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imgSendMessage);
    edit_delete=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imgEditDelete);
    specificMissCall=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imgMissCall);

    saveContact.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {



        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            v.setEnabled(false);
            ((ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imgSaveContact)).clearAnimation();
            ((ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imgSaveContact)).setAnimation(animation1);
            ((ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imgSaveContact)).startAnimation(animation1);
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });
```

Here is method,
How i can get specific imageview id in onAnimationEnd

```
@Override
public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    if (animation==animation1) 
    {
        if (isBackOfCardShowing) 
        {
            ((ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imgSaveContact)).setImageResource(R.drawable.contact);
        } 
        else 
        {
            ((ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imgSaveContact)).setImageResource(R.drawable.contact);
        }
        ((ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imgSaveContact)).clearAnimation();
        ((ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imgSaveContact)).setAnimation(animation2);
        ((ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imgSaveContact)).startAnimation(animation2);
    } 
    else 
    {
        isBackOfCardShowing=!isBackOfCardShowing;
        findViewById(R.id.imgSaveContact).setEnabled(true);
        Intent i=new Intent(HomeScreen.this,MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance..

Comment: But in onAnimationEnd() how i can get the imageview id ?

Comment: No intention to at least acknowledge my answer so I'm going to remove it. More wasted time...